# Laravel 500 error no logs

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu

First of all, according to stackoverflow, this problem occurs when something is wrong with permissions of `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` directories. And I tried literally every advice on that with no luck.

I was happy user of Xubuntu 16.04 at my old laptop, developed one project. Using `docker-compose` to set up development environment. Yesterday I bought brand new PC, installed Kubuntu 18.04, installed docker and everything I need to work.

Cloned repository, ran `composer install`, `docker-compose up`, then `php artisan migrate` and `php artisan storage:link`. But when I try to open website in browser, I get 500 error with empty body response.

APP_DEBUG is set to true.

6 hours later I'm here with literally zero results. Tried dozens of solutions found here and on forums ([just example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)).

I even did a little experiment: removed project directory from my old laptop, cloned it from scratch, installed everything required and it worked. Without any permission problem.

And what kills me more: there are no logs inside docker containers, no logs inside laravel directory, just nothing.

Please help! What's wrong? Maybe it's Kubuntu? Maybe it's 18.04? Maybe it's newer docker version?

P.S. Right now `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` directories are owned by `alex:alex` and has 775 permissions. Exactly same as at my laptop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a `dd($exception->getMessage());` to the [exception handler class](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/90b6165a2acc7d873100f358664a3df824051755/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L37) right before line 37. Run the request and check the response.

If that doesn't avail anything, verify the request is hitting the webserver by checking access and error logs. Check system logs also using `dmesg` and similar.

Since you mention Docker, if you're using nginx, be sure your site configuration is not being overwritten when running `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Or my god, you did impossible! After inserting that line, I finally got a error message about DB connection issues. Thank you very much!

Comment: For me, the issue was that my exception handler took an `Exception` instead of a `Throwable` after upgrading laravel. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like error is probably either related with storage permissions that should be 777, or with ownershp, or with app's bootstrap, before it even runs your files, when it pulls out configuration setup.

Check the .env configuration, and config files in config directory for any errors.

For storage switch to 777 permissions

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

For configuration issues, try first with

```
php artisan config:clear
```

From the console.

Comment: After spending so much time, found out that it was permissions error. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux server it may be selinux permissions. 
Try setting selinux as passive:

in terminal type:

```
setenforce 0
```

then see if you see errors.  If it works as should you want to turn selinux back on:

```
setenforce 1
```

Then give directory writable with selinux command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path
```